What is the number after CMakeLists.txt in QTCreator project overview?
In QTCreator, at the project overview, after CMakeLists.txt a mysterious number is shown. See picture (71 there).
What is this number?
I think it appeared first after I updated to QTCreater 15.0.0, not sure though.
Documentation eg at https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-how-to-view-cmake-project-contents.html didn't give a clue.


After some investigation I've found this:
In the project overview QtCreator when a CMakeLists.txt defines multiple targets, QtCreator (from version 15?) shows CmakeLists.txt for each target.
This is actually the same CMakeList.txt file for each of these targets.
The number is the line number where this target is defined.
I cannot find any documentation about this.

I thinks it is this ticket : https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-31362
which is mentioned on https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt-creator/qt-creator.git/about/dist/changelog/changes-15.0.0.md?h=15.0
